# How can I recover a blockchain.info wallet from a 17 word phrase?

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I have a wallet at blockchain.info which I've opened about 4 years ago.
Right now I cannot access it. It looks like the site is sending me a verification email, but sadly I don't know which address it uses.
If I use the "I've lost my 2FA Device" option, I have to enter my mail, but it keep telling me that the mail address is not correct (I've tried my main mail and 3 other mail addresses that I've used to use).
If I use the "I've lost my Wallet Password" option (although I have the password), I have to enter a 12 word phrase. I have a **17** word phrase and I've tried to use the first 12 words and the last 12 words, but no luck - I cannot even press the "continue" button.
I've contacted the site's support a few times but haven't got any answer at all.

Is there a way for me to recover my wallet directly from the 17 word phrase?

Comment: As the question was originally asked, the only answer I could think of was that only the customer support can help you. However, I've edited your question now to emphasize an underlying question that might help solve your issue. I hope somebody knows how to help you.

Comment: The updated recovery URL is: https://login.blockchain.com/wallet/forgot-password But don't take my word for it, the original https://blockchain.info/wallet/forgot-password link you used does redirect into this now.

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain.info's legacy wallet phrase decryption is here:

https://blockchain.info/wallet/forgot-password

Answer (score -1):

The updated blockchain wallet only has a 12 word phrase. I had this same issue a couple of months ago. Try this link, enter the 17 word phrase and you will get your password: https://blockchain.info/wallet/forgot-password

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this is not the case - the link helps to recover a lost password, but my password is good. The issue is that the site sends me a verification mail to unknown address.