# Restore blockchain.com wallet(s) in case the company goes away?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, ethereum, backup

So I have some funds on an blockchain.com wallet. Actually it's multiple wallets (some ETH, some BTC)

I followed [the backup procedure](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/209564506-Make-a-Wallet-Backup) and wrote 12 English words on a sheet of paper.

There is [an answer about password recovery](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54586/how-can-i-recover-a-blockchain-info-wallet-from-a-17-word-phrase) but it still needs the company to be existent.

Will there a way to recover the wallets from those passwords or is this just a fancy way of password recovery?
If not, what's a better way to backup the wallets?

EDIT: If found [some background](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001298143-Your-Secret-Private-Key-Recovery-Phrase-The-Failsafe) about how it seems to work.
It seems to work using BIP44 / BIP39. But this leads to more questions:

1. Is this only working for my bitcoin wallet, not for ETH?
2. Is also the wallet address encoded in the words or only the passphrase?

Answer (score 2):

I tried it. It works independent from the company.

I downloaded the exodus client and was able to restore my wallet there.

The only risk with a web-wallet like blockchain.com is, that the company could theoretically access to funds and withdraw them from my wallet, if they go bankrupt.

So it seems a better approach for use an offline wallet and transfer the funds to a new exodus wallet or something similar.